# sub-strings replacements according to some mapping

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

Given a string, I need to replace substrings according to a given mapping. The mapping determines where to start the replacement, the length of text to be replaced and the replacement string. The mapping is according to the following scheme:

```
public struct mapItem
{
    public int offset;
    public int length;
    public string newString;
}
```

For example: given a mapping `{{0,3,"frog"},{9,3,"kva"}}` and a string

```
"dog says gav"
```

we replace starting at position 0 a substring of the length 3 to the "frog", i.e.

```
dog - > frog
```

and starting the position 9 a substring of the length 3 to the "kva", i.e.

```
gav->kva
```

The new string becomes:

```
"frog says kva"
```

How can I do it efficiently?

Comment: no - it is semantic writing.Actually a get an array of structs each struct

Answer (score 2):

You have to take care that replacements take into account the shift produced by preceding replacements. Also using a `StringBuilder` is more efficient, as is doesn't allocate new memory at each operation as `string` operations do. (Strings are invariant, which means that a completely new string is created at each string operation.)

```cs
var maps = new List<MapItem> { ... };
var sb = new StringBuilder("dog says gav");
int shift = 0;
foreach (MapItem map in maps.OrderBy(m => m.Offset)) {
    sb.Remove(map.Offset + shift, map.Length);
    sb.Insert(map.Offset + shift, map.NewString);
    shift += map.NewString.Length - map.Length;
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

The `OrderBy` makes sure that the replacements are executed from left to right. If you know that the mappings are provided in this order, you can drop the `OrderBy`.

Another simpler way is to begin with the replacements at the right end and work backwards, so that the character shifts do not alter the positions of not yet executed replacements:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("dog says gav");
foreach (MapItem map in maps.OrderByDescending(m => m.Offset)) {
    sb.Remove(map.Offset, map.Length);
    sb.Insert(map.Offset, map.NewString);
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

In case the mappings are already ordered in ascending order, a simple reverse `for`-statement seems appropriate:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("dog says gav");
for (int i = maps.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    MapItem map = maps[i];
    sb.Remove(map.Offset, map.Length);
    sb.Insert(map.Offset, map.NewString);
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: `shift` changes by the difference of lengths of the new string compared to the old string `map.NewString.Length - map.Length`. If both have the same length, `shift` doesn't change. If the new string is long, it increases. If the new string is shorter, it decreases. I changed my solution anyway to use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I have tested the three solutions using a more complex mapping that stresses the algorithms a bit more. They all run fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an `Extension Method` like below:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static string ReplaceSubstringByMap(this string str, List<mapItem> map)
    {
        int offsetShift = 0;

        foreach (mapItem mapItem in map.OrderBy(x => x.offset))
        {
            str = str.Remove(mapItem.offset + offsetShift, mapItem.length).Insert(mapItem.offset + offsetShift, mapItem.newString);
            offsetShift += mapItem.newString.Length - mapItem.length;
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

And invoke it like below:

```
var map = new List<mapItem>
              {
                  new mapItem
                      {
                          offset = 0,
                          length = 1,
                          newString = "frog"
                      },
                  new mapItem
                      {
                          offset = 9,
                          length = 1,
                          newString = "kva"
                      }
              };
string str = "dog says gav";
var result = str.ReplaceSubstringByMap(map);
```